# HERE SDK for iOS - switch Server Environments

Tags: ios, maps, here-api, environment

How can I change Environment for `HERE maps SDK` for `iOS` to `Consumer Integration Testing` (`CIT`)? I can see it mentioned on developer documentation, but nowhere it's written how to switch to it on `iOS SDK`. It's only mentioned that this environment uses different `api address`, but when using this `SDK` on `iOS` I don't need to set the api anywhere, just call some functions.

Comment: Can you paste a link where CIT is mentioned? I can only imagine that this may be possible for the REST APIs. At the moment, the HERE SDK for iOS does not allow to switch backends, so you'll always use production environments, if I am not wrong.

Comment: You right, I meant it mentioned on REST documentation, and I thought it would work also for the SDK on iOS. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by @Datasun , it is not possible to update the urls of HERE SDK. The SDK always use the production urls and cannot be modified to use CIT url of the underlying APIs.